# Install XP and its updates on several PCs

Tags: windows-xp, installation, updates

What's the fastes way to install Windows XP on 20 PCs? Currenlty I have XP on a cd but I was thinking about a network installation. Is that possible?

The second issue is about the updates. The version of XP that I have currently requires something like 100 updates. What's the fastest way to install them on all the PCs.
Is the best solution reported in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/240488/windows-xp-updates-on-a-fresh-install) still valid?

Thanks!

Comment: Are they identical PCs? (Same hardware).

Answer (score 2):

If they are similar hardware and will be starting from scratch, then you could just create a drive image and deploy that. It would take a few minutes to create the image and a few minutes per system to write it to the drive.

If the systems are different, then you could deploy a base install and then update the drivers as needed depending on just how different they are. You could also slipstream the drivers for *all* of the varying components into a single image, so that they install automatically when you start up the systems.

To avoid having to download the updates on each and every system, you can use either Microsoft’s official solution, [WSUS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb332157.aspx), or create an “update pack” to deploy using [WSUS Offline Update](http://www.wsusoffline.net/docs/) (with WSUSOU, you can package updates for Windows and Office).

Comment: You can use Clonezilla to create and deploy images.

Comment: @lucaghera You can use Clonezilla to create and deploy images.

Comment: Yup, [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/), [DriveImageXML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm/), even [Easeus](http://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/).